# A technical problem about Encounter Levels

Tags: dnd-3.5e, experience-points

I have a question on how to give the correct experience to my party.
In the first fight they had:

- 6 x Skeletons (6 x CR 1/3 = EL 2)
- 1 x Ogre Skel. (CR 3)
- 1 x Level 2 Cleric (CR 2)
- 2 x Gnoll (2 x CR 1 = EL 2)

According with the table in the DM manual, page 49 (Italian ed.), I have something like 4 creatures on CR 2 (except for the big skel.) and this should be a EL 6. The party is composed by 5 adventurers on level 4 so, looking at the other table they should get **2.400 experience points**, more or less.

The second fight happened when they were resting, so they had no access to their best spells and they had to fight:

- 6 x Gnolls (6 x CR 1 = EL 5 really, you serious WotC?)
- 1 x Human Cleric lvl 2 (CR 2)
- 1 x Troglodyte Cleric lvl 2 (CR 3)

Considering the condition of the party and the number of enemies, this should be something like EL 7 or 8, worthing **3.200 or 4.200 experience points**.

Am I doing well or not?

Comment: It's "Return to Temple of Elemental Evil" campaign set.

Answer (score 11):

## Encounter Level doesn't affect XP Awards

This is explained in greater detail in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Experience Rewards (36-7), but creatures generate XP through their Challenge Ratings. The DM *can* modify both the Challenge Rating (hence the XP award) and the Encounter Level of an encounter as described in Modifying XP Awards and Encounter Levels (*DMG* 39). This makes Table 3–1: Encounter Numbers (*DMG* 49) unimportant when determining XP; rely instead on Table 2–6: Experience Point Awards (Single Monster).

I've broken down both encounters below. *Note:* PCs will like your numbers better.

### Encounter 1

If all the creatures in the first encounter are overcome, the encounter generates 2,600 XP for level 4 PCs. With 5 level 4 PCs participating, each PC earns 520 XP.

#### Breakdown

- 6 CR 1/3 skeletons (300 XP each but each divided by 3 equals 100 XP each for a total of 600 XP)<sup>1</sup>
- 2 CR 1 gnolls (300 XP each for a total of 600 XP)
- 1 CR 2 cleric (600 XP)
- 1 CR 3 ogre skeleton (800 XP)

### Encounter 2

If all the creatures in the second encounter are overcome, the encounter generates 3,200 XP for level 4 PCs. With 5 level 4 PCs participating, each PC earns 640 XP.

#### Breakdown

- 6 CR 1 gnolls (300 XP each for a total of 1,800 XP)<sup>2</sup>
- 1 CR 2 human Clr2 (600 XP)
- 1 CR 2 troglodyte Clr2 (800 XP)

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The division is as per the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Monsters Below CR 1, which says

> Some monsters are fractions of a Challenge Rating. For instance, a single orc is not a good challenge for even a 1st-level party, although two might be. You could think of an orc as approximately CR 1/2. For these cases, calculate XP as if the creature were CR 1, then divide the result by 2. (37)

<sup>**2**</sup> 6 CR 1 [gnolls](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/gnoll.htm) have, in fact, a combined Encounter Level of 5. Remember that gnolls, unlike the previous skeleton horde, think independently and employ tactics. They like setting ambushes and flanking, and a critical hit from a gnoll's battleaxe (after switching to a two-handed grip as a free action after dropping the shield as a free action and using the feat Power Attack) can deal over 40 points of damage.

Comment: Uhm... there's something I can't get from your explaination: the numbers are the same. What am I missing?

Comment: @IssamTP Our numbers *are* close but not identical. If you continued using EL instead of CR, at higher levels the numeric differences would be much more pronounced (for example, 12 CR 5 creatures earns a party of 5 level 12 adventurers 144 XP each, but 1 CR 12 creature earns the same party 720 XP each, yet both are an EL 12 encounter).

Comment: I guess I should read again the manual...

Comment: @IssamTP It's not that big of a deal if everyone's happy. As an aside, so you know, many folks—even by-the-book rules monkeys such as I—dispense with XP altogether. XP as a currency is a deeply flawed paradigm anyway, and there are numerous, playtested workarounds for the most common expenditure, [item creation](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/35006/8610). Just something to consider.

Comment: Even if you don’t dispense with XP, it’s entirely workable to fudge it to a greater or lesser extent. Even more so if you’re comfortable with different levels in the same party.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [Encounter Calculator](http://www.d20srd.org/extras/d20encountercalculator/) if you don't already know of it.

Comment: I can't pinpoint where but there must be something wrong in calculations, since the Encounter Calculator gives different results.

Comment: @Zachiel I'm sorry but I didn't grasped your comment realy well (not first language). Do you doubt Calculator or IssamTP's calculations? They assume 4 CR2 creatures instead of a bunch from the first part for simplicity as I got it. Don't think 200 exp make significant difference here.

Comment: You said IssamTP's calculations were ok but the automatic calculator gives different results. Hey I Can Chan's answer has why (and points out that the difference grows with levels)

Comment: @Zachiel Got it. Really becomes invalid in corner cases. I think, I'll leave the answer though for the link.